# React Hooks = TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, hook

Пробую React Hooks. При рендере ошибка:
Пример взят  [тут](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)
[image: ошибка]

Вот код:
App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: какая у вас версия реакта?

Comment: "react": "^16.7.0", так же я пробовал "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2", результат тот же

Comment: попробуйте убрать ^, она может сбивать с толку npm

Comment: Убрал, переустановил, результат тот же, та же ошибка. 
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: а сам react-dom тоже 16.7? Просто по приведённому выше коду, вроде ошибок не замечаю

Comment: Да тоже, такие версии установил crea-react-app. 16.7.0 релиз показывает на сайте реакт как текущий.
Вот в чендж логах как последний релиз https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1670-december-19-2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте укзали что хуки перенесли в следуйщую альфа-версию. 16.7.0 релизнулся но без хуков, хуки щас в версии 16.8.0-alpha.0.

> Hooks are an upcoming feature that lets you use state and other React features without writing a class. They’re currently in React v16.8.0-alpha.0.

Answer (score 2):

На странице, с которой Вы берете пример, явно написано:

> Hooks are an upcoming feature that lets you use state and other React
>   features without writing a class. They’re currently in React
>   v16.7.0-alpha.

а Вы как я понял используете **16.7.0**. Переустановите пакеты еще раз. Эта ошибка возникает при конфликте новой версии `react` и старой `react-dom`:

```
rm -rf /node_modules
yarn add react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.2 react@16.7.0-alpha.2
```